# mod_rewrite RewriteRule in .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing a strange issue with mod_rewrite RewriteRule in .htaccess.

Here's my minimal .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^phpinfo phpinfo.php [L]
```

The above Rewrite results in 404 Not Found. However, suffixing anything to `^phpinfo` works which is unintended and undesired.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^phpinfophp phpinfo.php [L]
```

Please help me with making the actual RewriteRule work.

Thanks,

Shyam Singh

Comment: Try disabling MultiViews, `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^phpinfo phpinfo.php [L]
> ```

MultiViews often causes problems in instances likes this, because its job is to detected slightly misspelled URLs, multiple possible file matches (different extensions, etc.) and correct them – and it interferes here, because it sees a request for `phpinfo` and finds a corresponding file `phpinfo.php`

Deactivate it using `Options -MultiViews`, that should fix the problem.